# How to find top K when K is too large for memory

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, mapreduce

Let's say there is a large file with N elements and I want to find the top K largest elements from that file and output to a new file.

If N is large but K is small, I could use a min-heap of size K while doing a buffered read of the input file.

However, if K is also a huge number and we cannot hold K elements in memory, then the min-heap approach would not work.

In such scenarios, how can we get the desired output? I am wondering if we can do something similar to external merge sort where we have intermediate files on disk that we merge iteratively. However, I can't think of an exact solution

Comment: *"wondering if we can do something similar to external merge sort"* - Why only *similar*? Why not external merge sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some `L` that comfortably fits in memory, use [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to pick a random set of `L` elements in a single passs.

How many of the `L` elements do we expect to find in the top `K`?  Well, let `p = K/N`.  Each element is in the top `k` with probability `p`.  This is a random variable with mean `p` and variance `p*(1-p)`.  Add together `L` of them and you get approximately a standard normal with mean `p*L` and variance `p*(1-p)*L`, and therefore standard deviation `sqrt(p*(1-p)*L)`.  (If `p*L < 20`, you're better off going to a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) instead of a normal, but the same principle will apply.)

So we can sort the sample, and find the bounds of a number of confidence intervals.  Let's pick 9 points in the sample, such that they would be -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 standard deviations away from where we expect them to be.  Then we can do a second pass and split into 10 files on those boundaries, with a decision tree that tests the ends, then the middle, then 2, -2, then  finds the exact range if needed.  Keep count of the number of things in those files.

The result is that in 2 passes, with odds of under 1/million of failing, we've narrowed the result down to a file with `N/sqrt(L)` elements.  Repeat until it is small enough.

Even when we do fail, we've at least partitioned it down to a smaller file, and can repeat the second pass using new partition points based on what we've learned.

If `L` is a million, then with odds of better than 99.9999%, 99% of the file winds up in/or out of our top `k` with only 2 reads, one write, and 2 comparisons.  The rest of the work is a rounding error compared to that.

Note that if the file is on a distributed file system, this calculation can be distributed and parallelized.  The overall work remains similar, but the number of passes will increase.  However with 2 passes reducing the size of the problem by a factor of 1000, the number of passes is `O(log(N))` with a good constant.

Answer (score 0):

You could partition the input using a pivot value:

- Choose a pivot value from the input file (could be the first value, or a randomly selected item, or a median of three randomly selected, ...etc)
- Partition the file into file  and file , where all values in file  are less than the pivot.
- If file  has more than  values:

  - Repeat the procedure with file  as input file, with the same
- Otherwise:

  - Append file  to the output file
  - Reduce  with the number of values in file
  - If  is not zero, repeat the procedure with file  as input file, with this reduced

If at a certain point  is small enough to store  values in memory, then use the heap solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: This requires a lot of passes through very large files.  My solution tries to minimize that, and uses far less IO and computation as a result.

Comment: Please define "a lot". It is logarithmic.